# A non-null String must be provided to a Text widget - flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm new to flutter and I'm learning it via a course on Udemy in this course we learn to create a simple BMI calculator which I did but the problem is that my app stats working perfectly and I can change the numbers and gender on it and sometimes it shows the result

> <════════ Exception caught by widgets library ════════════
>
> The following assertion was thrown building ResultsPage(dirty):
>
> A non-null String must be provided to a Text widget.
>
> 'package:flutter/src/widgets/text.dart':
>
> Failed assertion: line 381 pos 10: 'data != null'
>
> The relevant error-causing widget was:
>
> ResultsPage
> file:///D:/FlutterProjects/bmi_calculator/lib/input_page.dart:223:47
>
> When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
>
> #2      new Text (package:flutter/src/widgets/text.dart:381:10)
>
> #3      ResultsPage.build (package:bmi_calculator/results_page.dart:50:19)
>
> #4      StatelessElement.build (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4749:28)
>
> #5      ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4675:15)
>
> #6      Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4369:5)>

I don't know exactly what the problem is I tried to read similar problems here but unfortunately, I couldn't find which text widget I pass empty. this is the code for my results page

```
import 'package:bmi_calculator/bottom_button.dart';
import 'package:bmi_calculator/constants.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'reusable_card.dart';

class ResultsPage extends StatelessWidget {
  ResultsPage(
      {@required this.resultText,
      @required this.bmiResult,
      @required this.interpretation});

  final String resultText;
  final String bmiResult;
  final String interpretation;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Your Results'),
      ),
      body: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
        children: <Widget>[
          Expanded(
            child: Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
              alignment: Alignment.bottomLeft,
              child: Text(
                'Your Results',
                style: kTitleStyle,
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Expanded(
            flex: 5,
            child: ReusableCard(
              colour: kActiveCardColour,
              cardChild: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Text(
                    bmiResult,
                    style: kResultTextStyle,
                  ),
                  Text(
                    resultText,
                    style: kNumberTextStyle.copyWith(
                      fontSize: 100.0,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    ),
                  ),
                  Text(
                    interpretation,
                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                    style: kBMIResultTextStyle,
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
          BottomButton(
              onTap: () => Navigator.pop(context), buttonTitle: 'ReCalculate')
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

---

EDIT:
Thanks, everyone for responding to my issue.
All of the solutions worked for me and stopped my app from crashing. and I used this method

```
          Text(
            bmiResult ?? '',
            style: kResultTextStyle,
          ),
          Text(
            resultText ?? '',
            style: kNumberTextStyle.copyWith(
              fontSize: 100.0,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
            ),
          ),
          Text(
            interpretation ?? '',
            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
            style: kBMIResultTextStyle,
          )
```

to keep my code short and concise. But, I also realized something else in my code. I have three conditions in my app, which as you can guess are underweight, normal, and overweight. When I calculate the results, the application shows `resultText` and `interpretation` only if it's overweight. if the result is normal or underweight, it doesn't show them, and I assume it means this is what makes my app to crash because somehow it can't get the Text strings which I assigned for normal and underweight.

Answer (score 0):

Either initialize the values to be not null or simply using ?? Operator to make this empty string when null is detected

```
                children: <Widget>[
                  Text(
                    bmiResult ?? "",
                    style: kResultTextStyle,
                  ),
                  Text(
                    resultText ?? "",
                    style: kNumberTextStyle.copyWith(
                      fontSize: 100.0,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    ),
                  ),
                  Text(
                    interpretation ?? "",
                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                    style: kBMIResultTextStyle,
                  )
                ],
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to check if your variables : resultText, bmiResult, interpretation are not null because the Text widget cannot receive null value.

```
                  Text(
                    this.bmiResult != null ? this.bmiResult : "",
                    style: kResultTextStyle,
                  ),
                  Text(
                    this.resultText != null ? this.resultText : "",
                    style: kNumberTextStyle.copyWith(
                      fontSize: 100.0,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    ),
                  ),
                  Text(
                    this.interpretation != null ? this.interpretation : "",
                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                    style: kBMIResultTextStyle,
                  )
```

Or, you can just use the null-coalescing operator ?? to simplify :

```
this.interpretation ?? ""
```

Answer (score 0):

You have at least 3 `Text` widgets where the `data` property is initialized from class members: `resultText`, `bmiResult`, `interpretation`. It looks like one of these member is `null`. To avoid the `red screen` you need to:

1. Call widget with initialized props:

```dart
ResultsPage(
  resultText: 'Result Text',
  bmiResult: 'BMI result',
  interpretation: 'interpretation',
)
```

2. Set default values for `ResultsPage`'s properties in constructor (e.g. empty string)

```dart
ResultsPage({this.resultText = '', this.bmiResult = '', this.interpretation = ''})
```

3. Use null aware feature in `Text()` widgets:

```dart
Text(resultText ?? 'n/a'),
```

This means that Text `data` will be equal to value of `resultText` if it **is not** `null`, or `n/a` if **is** `null`.
empty string will be used as data.